# user account for SMB

Tags: networking, smb, user

is it possible to create user accounts under windows just for home network sharing?

I don't want the account to appear in the list of login windows. I don't need it to have its own set of folders, etc...

I just need many different login credential for my SMB shares.

Answer (score 0):

What version of windows is this? This microsoft link talks about using the MMC and adding in the Users snapin to manipulate users.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-a-user-account-to-a-group

Typically the professional/business version of windows is required to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is all set up on the server when you configure the samba shares. There is no reason to create any windows users at all. Just create your shared folders with differrent username/password combinations.

The first time you try to connect to a samba share, windows will ask you for credentials. You just need to give the appropriate ones for each share.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You have to create a normal user, then remove it from all groups and add it to the BackupOperators group.

Such user can not log on to desktop on your PC, but you can give it the permissions for a share.